# Sending pushbullet meassages from my raspberry pi not possible: Error message "SSL: CERTIFICATE VERIFY FAILED" received

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pushbullet

Since June 26th 2023 I cannot send meassages from my raspberry pi via pushbullet.
I have not changed anything on my device. The following error message is received:
SSL: CERTIFICATE VERIFY FAILED.

sudo update-ca-certificates did not work.